# How to duplicate a struct with char* and point on it?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, duplicates

I'm new in C programming and would love to get some help.

I have this struct :

```
typedef struct house
{
   int numOfRooms;
   char* houseName;
}HOUSE,*pHOUSE;
```

I want to create a function that gets a pointer to HOUSE and returns a new pointer to same HOUSE that is located in a different place in memory - the purpose is to be able to change one pointer without changing both : 
I will try to be clearer :

```
pHOUSE duplicate_house(pHOUSE house)
{
  pHOUSE newh = (pHOUSE)calloc(1,sizeof(HOUSE));
  newh = house 
 //I get here a pointer that points on the same house.. so If I change for exmample:
 //  newh->numOfRooms = 9 - > both will change and I don't want it to happen!


}
```

I read that we can use : memcpy_s 
but here If I only had integers inside the struct it could be easy , here I have char * , so means I need also to copy the `char * houseName` separately?
what can I do? How can I copy an object that has multiply types like `char *`?
and If I had an array ? what could I do ?

```
typedef struct house
{
    int numOfRooms;
     char* houseName;
     struct house *houses[10];
}HOUSE,*pHOUSE;
```

how can I copy that?

thank u very much!

Comment: Typedef'ing the struct adds complexity for no benefit.  The struct already has a type, so the compiler can already detect type mismatches.  You might as well typedef ints; it's exactly the same.

Comment: Is it just me who actually finds `struct house *` _easier_ to decode than mixtures of `pHOUSE` and `HOUSE`?

Comment: Not only have most experienced programmers an aversion agains `typedef`s for pointer types, also hiding several `typedef` in one is really bad style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy both the structure as well as all memory that's managed *by* the structure. Like so:

```
pHOUSE copy(pHOUSE house)
{
    pHOUSE newHouse = malloc(sizeof *newHouse);      // allocate

    if (pHOUSE)
    {
        memcpy(newHouse, house, sizeof *newHouse);   // or "*newHouse = *house;"
        size_t const len = strlen(house->houseName);
        newHouse->houseName = malloc(len + 1);

        if (!newHouse->houseName) { free newHouse; return NULL; }

        strncpy(newHouse->houseName, house->houseName, len + 1);
    }
    return pHOUSE;
}
```

As you can see, the error handling with *two* allocations is already getting very cumbersome. If you had multiple internal allocations, the only way to remain sane is to use `goto`s systematically to create the appropriate cleanup points.

---

Example to illustrate the last point:

```
struct FooLish
{
    char * p1;
    char * p2;
    char * p3;
};

struct FooLish * copy(struct FooLish const * oldFoo)
{
    struct FooLish * newFoo = malloc(sizeof *newFoo);
    if (!newFoo) { goto end0; }

    {
        size_t const len = strlen(oldFoo->p1);
        newFoo->p1 = malloc(strlen(len + 1);
        if (!newFoo->p1) { goto end1; }
        strncpy(newFoo->p1, oldFoo->p1, len + 1);
    }
    {
        size_t const len = strlen(oldFoo->p2);
        newFoo->p2 = malloc(strlen(len + 1);
        if (!newFoo->p2) { goto end2; }
        strncpy(newFoo->p2, oldFoo->p2, len + 1);
    }
    {
        size_t const len = strlen(oldFoo->p3);
        newFoo->p3 = malloc(strlen(len + 1);
        if (!newFoo->p3) { goto end3; }
        strncpy(newFoo->p3, oldFoo->p3, len + 1);
    }

    return newFoo;

end3:
   free(newFoo->p2);
end2:
   free(newFoo->p1);
end1:
   free(newFoo);
end0:
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but by using strncpy() with len, won't you lose the trailing NULL?

Comment: Also, I wouldn't use memcpy() to copy the struct over.  Just use the equals operator, e.g. "newHouse = *house".

Comment: @BlankXavier: Thanks, you're right. I changed it to `len + 1`, which is correct. You could probably also use `strcpy` (since you know your buffer has the right length), and it might even be slightly more efficient, but that feels like setting a wrong example.

Comment: first - thanks! second. i have a couple of questions , why are you using in the memcpy : sizeof *newHouse and not HOUSE ? is there a difference? And - I saw that @BlankXavier wrote to use "=" , why? it works like that? it will copy everything?

Comment: @user1391863: You should never repeat yourself. There's no reason to repeat the type name, since it's implied by the type of the expression `*newHouse`. Assignment on a struct performs assignment on each element, so arguably that's nicer style. Take your pick.